# Keep the user's configuration when running emacs in sudo mode

Tags: php, emacs, syntax, colors, sudo

I have to run emacs in sudo mode, to edit some .html or .php files in my /var/www directory. 
When I run it in normal-user mode, there's no problem with the syntax, and the colors (I installed the php-mode.el extension). Unfortunately when I run it in sudo mode, I lose this configuration.
Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: check if you and root have the same vi alias: `alias vi` vs. `sudo alias vi`

Comment: Yes, I enabled the aliases for root by setting in my .zshrc file : alias sudo="sudo " but, I can't see why it could help. Also, I'm not using vim

Comment: @Alexander, why would an alias on `vi` have anything to do with Emacs?

Comment: I meant emacs, not vi. Do you have an alias for emacs? Or do you have different emacs config for root and your local user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Unfortunately when I run it in sudo mode, I loose this configuration, which is sad.

That's completely expected. When you run a command with `sudo` you're running it  as a different user, usually `root`. In most cases the target user's configuration will be used.

> Is there any way to get it back ?

I believe the best option here is to run Emacs normally and then *edit the file* as `root` using [TRAMP](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/). In this case I think prefixing the file with `/sudo::` will do the trick, e.g. `C-x C-f /sudo::/var/www/html/foo.php RET`. Emacs will prompt you for your password, just like `sudo` would on the command line.

TRAMP does a lot more than letting you edit certain files as `root` via `sudo`, and it is probably worth your time to browse its manual.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that you would ever need to run `sudo emacs`, and it's bad practice to run things as root unnecessarily.

The `sudoedit` command / `sudo -e` option exists for the purpose of editing files owned by other users. The editor which will be used is described in the manual (`man sudo`) under the description for the `-e` option:

> The editor specified by the policy is run to edit the temporary files.  The sudoers policy uses the SUDO_EDITOR, VISUAL and EDITOR environment variables (in that order).  If none of SUDO_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, the first program listed in the editor sudoers(5) option is used.

With this approach, you will be editing a file as your normal user, and hence with your normal editor config.

Alternatively, use the Tramp methods built into Emacs, as per Chris' answer (which is most likely simpler if you are editing many files).

If these are files you essentially need to have write access to in general, perhaps you should allocate yourself to a group with write access.

Comment: While using`sudo -e` does indeed use my user's config instead of root's - I noticed that changes to the file I was editing only appeared when I closed emacs. Usually when you save to a file - you see the changes on the server. Often there are workflows where you need to make a change, save, test, and iterate. The behavior of `sudo -e` makes that problematic.